# Javascript if statement come back false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console.log

I don't understand why the `temp` variable is only returning false. I have tried `==` just to see if using strict comparison was the issue, but it didn't change. Just to double check, I'm making sure the variables are of the same type by printing their type in console.

<del>Another odd thing that is happening is when I use this line, `console.log('temp = ' + temp);` to see what is inside of `temp`, nothing but a blank space will print. But if I use `console.log(temp);`, it will print what is stored in `temp`.</del> The `console.log('temp = ' + temp);` seems to have fixed itself, so nevermind with that issue, but it's still not returning true.

```
var upFormData = formData.toUpperCase();
console.log('Form Data: ' + upFormData);
degrees[str] = [];
degrees[str][0] = data[0];

for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var temp = data[i][5].toUpperCase();
    console.log(temp);
    //console.log('temp = ' + temp);
    console.log('upFormData = ' + upFormData + ' ' + typeof upFormData + ' ' + typeof temp);

    if(upFormData === temp)
    {
        console.log('MATCH');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('NOT A MATCH');
        //console.log(temp);
        //console.log('upFormData = ' + upFormData + ' ' + typeof upFormData + ' ' + typeof temp);
    }
```

*Results of this script:*

[image]

Can someone help explain what I'm not doing? And please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't make sense. What is the content of the variable named 'data' in the 4th line?
Try to add information to make this a self containing example so we can help you better.

Comment: `if(upFormData === temp)` -- I don't see anything that tells us if this condition is `true` or `false`. can you please explain why you think this should be `true`

Comment: Why `if(upFormData === temp)` should be true? What is the value of `data[i][5].toUpperCase()`? What does `data` contains? Please provide more info in order to help you

Comment: `trim` both of them and share the result. `upFormData.trim() === temp.trim()`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes! this was the problem. Sorry for the poor information, `data` is just a double array with `data[i][5]` just being something with two letters in it. I must be putting a space is that spot. Thank you for the help. If you post it as an answer ill make sure to mark it as much.

Comment: You should remove or at least strike trough information that are no longer valid. Having to read the question back and forth to figure out what information is correct and what is not, is not very helpful.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I ll do that in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are want to check if the value entered in form (`formData`) is in `data` array.

Use `some`

```
var upFormData = formData.trim().toUpperCase();
var hasFormData = data.some( s => s[5].trim().toUpperCase() === upFormData ); //hasFormData will return true if any value matches
```

If you want to `filter` out `data` values which matches `forData` value, use `filter`

```
var matchedData = data.filter( s => s[5].trim().toUpperCase() === upFormData );
```